# How can I handle "if may be missing an else clause" when using an if inside of a map?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I'm working on a code challenge which will detect case-insensitive anagrams of a given word from a list of words.

My first cut is to use something like this:

```
pub fn anagrams_for(s: &'static str, v: &[&'static str]) -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let mut outputs: Vec<&str> = vec![];

    // Find the case-insensitive, sorted word to check
    let mut s_sorted: Vec<_> = s.to_string().to_lowercase().chars().collect();
    s_sorted.sort();

    for word in v {
        // Case-desensitize and sort each word in the slice
        let mut word_sorted: Vec<_> = word.to_string().to_lowercase().chars().collect();
        word_sorted.sort();

        // if the case-insensitive words are the same post sort and not presort (to avoid self-anagrams), add it to the vector
        if word_sorted == s_sorted && s.to_string().to_lowercase() != word.to_string().to_lowercase() {
            outputs.push(word)
        }
    }
    outputs
}
```

This works as expected, but is not very idiomatic. I'm now trying a second iteration which uses more functional features of Rust:

```
pub fn anagrams_for(s: &'static str, v: &[&'static str]) -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let mut s_sorted: Vec<_> = s.to_string().to_lowercase().chars().collect();
    s_sorted.sort();

    v.iter().map(&|word: &str| {
        let mut word_sorted: Vec<_> = word.to_string().to_lowercase().chars().collect();
        word_sorted.sort();

        if word_sorted == s_sorted && s.to_string().to_lowercase() != word.to_string().to_lowercase() {
            word
        } 
    }).collect()
}
```

I'm currently getting a few errors (most of which I could likely resolve), but the one I'm interested in solving is

> ```
> if may be missing an else clause:
>  expected `()`,
>     found `&str`
> (expected (),
>     found &-ptr) [E0308]
> ```

This is because in the case of a non-anagram, `map` attempts to push something into the vector (seemingly `()`).

How can I handle this? It's possible that `map` isn't the best idiom because it requires some operation to be performed on *each* element in a list, not a subset (maybe `filter`?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, the problem is that in the non-anagram-case your closure (the `|| { ... }` block) doesn't return a value.

You can solve this by using [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) instead of `map`. That function takes a closure that returns `Option<U>` instead of `U`, so the last expression of your closure looks something like:

```
if /* ... */ {
    Some(word)
} else {
    None
}
```

---

Unrelated to the main question, some notes on your code:

- You can remove the `.to_string()` calls before `.to_lowercase()` calls. the latter method belongs to the type `str`, so it works fine. Calling `to_string()` adds unnecessary allocations.
- the `&` in front of the closure (`&|...|`) can most probably be removed...
- ... as can the `: &str` type annotation in the closures argument list

Comment: `filter_map` is cute, but if it returns `Optional<U>` and I want to only return the anagrams, I'd have to issue another `filter` checking `is_some`. This seems unnecessary. +1 for the tips and tricks!

Comment: What? No I think you misunderstood. `filter_map` already applies a filter and only retains the `Some(..)` elements and also unwraps those. Look at the examples in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map)

Comment: Whoops! Indeed, I did misunderstand... Sorry about that!

Comment: No problem :) Also: to get useful remarks on your code, you can ask on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust)

Comment: Yes, I typically try to ask there (not as often as I should, perhaps), but I thought since this was syntax related, better to post here.